# How to add a new column in a empty list from another list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
L=[[1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 8], [4, 5, 6, 0, 3, 8], [7, 8, 9, 0, 3, 8]]
```

another list

```
col=[0,2,3]
```

and an empty list `M = []`.

`col` list has the index of columns of `L` list that has to be copied to `M`.

So `M` should be `[[1,3,0],[4,6,0],[7,9,0]]`.

How can i do this??
I want `M` as a dataframe.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> L=[[1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 8], [4, 5, 6, 0, 3, 8], [7, 8, 9, 0, 3, 8]]
>>> col=[0,2,3]
>>> M = [[nums[i] for i in col] for nums in L]
>>> M
[[1, 3, 0], [4, 6, 0], [7, 9, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

With numpy you can use a list as list index:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 8], [4, 5, 6, 0, 3, 8], [7, 8, 9, 0, 3, 8]])
>>> col=[0,2,3]
>>> M = [row[col] for row in L]
>>> M
[array([1, 3, 0]), array([4, 6, 0]), array([7, 9, 0])]
>>> M = [list(row[col]) for row in L]
>>> M
[[1, 3, 0], [4, 6, 0], [7, 9, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) along with simple list comprehension to fetch your desired elements

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> L = [[1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 8], [4, 5, 6, 0, 3, 8], [7, 8, 9, 0, 3, 8]]
>>> col = col=[0,2,3]
>>> M = [list(itemgetter(*col)(i)) for i in l]
>>> M
[[1, 3, 0], [4, 6, 0], [7, 9, 0]]
```

To Convert it to `DataFrame` you can do

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(M)
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  1  3  0
1  4  6  0
2  7  9  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to put it out there, the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html) solution:

```
L=[[1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 8], [4, 5, 6, 0, 3, 8], [7, 8, 9, 0, 3, 8]]
col=[0,2,3]

solution = [[j for i, j in enumerate(sub) if i in col] for sub in L]
#[[1, 3, 0], [4, 6, 0], [7, 9, 0]]
```

This would work faster if `col` was a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
col={0,2,3}
```